# Selenium- len of text returns zero?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I want to get the len of a text field after calling .send_keys() method on and entering texts in.Although that after calling the method there are texts, the following len statement returns zero:

```
print len(driver.find_element_by_id('some id').text)
```

returns zero.

Is there anyway to overcome this problem and get the len of the field after having texts entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a text in a input area(textfield), you should get value of attribute.

```
print len(driver.find_element_by_id("textbox").get_attribute("value"))
```

Comment: It worked! Didn't know that as you enter something in a text field, it goes to the value attribute.Thanks.